# Nodejs API batch post with JSON data in body

Tags: sql-server, node.js, api, angular, npm

I'm building an Angular2 application with a Nodejs API for manipulating a Microsoft SQL Server using the NPM package 'mssql'. 
Everything works perfectly, but I can't figure out one thing.

I have to create a way to post a batch of users from a csv file? Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Added some code I already have (and works...)

Component:

```
`var array: Gebruiker[] = [];
array.push(model);
this.gebruikerService.insertGebruiker(array).subscribe(
...`
```

Service:

```
`insertGebruiker(data) {
    //Create headers for JSON data
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //create JSON from model
    var user = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log("JSON DATA = " + data);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/gebruikers/post', user, {headers: headers});
  }`
```

API:

```
router.post('/gebruikers/post', (req, res) => {
sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    //Change variable to JSON
    var data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(json)

    var count = Object.keys(json).length;

    var queryInsert = "INSERT INTO [Alg].[User] (FirstName, LastName, PrivateMail, UserName, Password, Auth, Enabled, Created, Manual, LastChanged, Staff) VALUES ";
    var queryVariables = "";
    var queryString = "";
    var counterForHowManyTimesTheQueryIsExecuted = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //new variables for new user
        console.log(i);
        console.log(count);
        var FirstName = json[i].Firstname;
        var LastName = json[i].LastName;
        var PrivateMail = json[i].PrivateMail;
        var UserName = json[i].UserName;
        var Password = json[i].Password;
        var Staff = "1";
        queryVariables += "('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', '" + PrivateMail + "', '" + UserName + "', '" + Password + "', 'manual', 1, GetDate(), 1, GetDate(), " + Staff + ")";
        if ((i % 1000 == 0 && i != 0) || i == count - 1) {
            queryVariables += "; ";
            queryString = queryInsert + queryVariables;
            queryVariables = "";
            counterForHowManyTimesTheQueryIsExecuted++;
            console.log(queryString);
            request.query(queryString, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    res.end("POST request finished! ");
                }
            });
            request.query();
        }
        else {
            queryVariables += ", ";
        }
    }

    console.log(counterForHowManyTimesTheQueryIsExecuted);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [csv-parse module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse). This will convert  CSV text input into arrays or objects

Following can be the algorithm:

- Upload the file
- Read the file using `fs` module
- Pass to `csv-parse` module. As mentioned it will return array of arrays
- Iterate it and insert into database

  ```
  var csvParser = require('csv-parse');
  fs.readFile(filePath, {
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   }, function(err, csvData) {
          if (err) {
             console.log(err);
           }
       csvParser(csvData, {
          delimiter: ','
         }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                 } else {
                   // Insert into database here
                      console.log(data);
                 }
              });
         });
  ```

Comment: Okay, this can be useful! But I need to send this data to a post in my Nodejs API. Can I parse that array of arrays into json format and then send it in the body of my post (in my service)?

Comment: It won't be wise to parse Csv at the client side. For a quick way. https://github.com/MounirMesselmeni/html-fileapi/blob/master/js/read-csv.js

Comment: there can be edge-cases which may be missed out while parsing the data at the client side. node.js has already well tested libraries ( e.g. `csv-parse` ) to do the job.

Comment: But how can I send that csv data to my API? It has to be able to send at least 10.000 users at one time...

Comment: So, I suggest you to  upload the csv file and parse it at the server side.

Comment: Please check my added code in the original question, maybe you can see what I have to achieve..

Comment: i got your intention, why don't you upload the file and parse it at the server side? Any limitation doing that?

Comment: Someone told me to send the data in JSON format in the body so I got fixated on that, I'm sorry! Okay, so I'm using the PrimeNG FileUploadModule to send the file to http://localhost:3000/api/gebruikers/csv. 

The documentation says this: Name of the request parameter to identify the files at backend. What does this mean? Just req.name? Because that's undefined...

Comment: Try `req.files.name`

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but I had some other stuf to do first. Now I'm back on this issue and I still can't acces the data from the file in my API. `req.files.name` gives me an error: Can't read property 'name' of undefined. So `files` didn't exist in the first place. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I found the npm package Multer and I figured out how that works! There have been some changes so your way doesn't work anymore I think, correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, many many thanks!!!